# How can I access vue-cookies in a vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cookies

In an action, I'm doing:

```js
this.$cookies.set("token", response.token, "7d");
this.$cookies.set("UserId", response.UserId, "7d");
```

But alas `$cookies` is not defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library and than access cookie like this in vuex store:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const getters = {
  isLoggedIn: function (state) {
    return !!state.email && !!Cookies.get('access_token')
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I somehow use `vue-cookies`?

Comment: `js-cookie` does everything I needed `vue-cookies` to do. In my case, there is no need to implement `vue-cookies` over `js-cookie`

Answer (score 7):

you can do  (in `store.js`)

```
import Vue from 'vue'

...

someAction () {
    Vue.prototype.$cookies.set("token", response.token, "7d");
}
```

Comment: How reasonable is it to import Vue?

Comment: @PavelLevin I have been using this pattern for quite a while, and have not found any drawbacks yet. You can safely import Vue anywhere in your project. Imports are properly encapsulated when bundled.

Answer (score 7):

When using `vue-cookies` in your app

In your `store.js`, you can

```
import cookie from 'vue-cookies'

.....

action(){
   cookie.get('token');
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Never ever allow a JWT cookie to be accessible by JS. This opens you up for a lot of security vulnerabilities. The accepted answer should never be implemented.

Use a http only and secure cookie only for a production application. Please redesign this part if you are building for production